# React Native : How can I get gestures onTouchStart, onTouchEnd and onTouchMove event positions ( like X and Y Coordinations) in Android

Tags: react-native, event-handling, touch, gesture

How would I get the coordinates of my onTouchEnd event. So I  touch or move figure anywhere within the display and I can retrieve the X, Y positioning of where it happened. onResponderRelease is not triggered in a onTouchEnd on Android,

### I've included example implementations for all of the gesture response event handlers, but have commented out most of them on my View to just provide the basic functionality: subscribing to all touch and move events

pseudo code would look like this :

```
<View
        style={this.props.style}
        ref={this._saveRef}
        onStartShouldSetResponder={(event) => {
          return this.handleDoubleTap({nativeEvent: 
          event.nativeEvent});
        }}
        onResponderGrant={this._onTouchStart}
        onResponderMove={this._onTouchMove}
        onResponderRelease={this._onTouchEnd}
        onResponderTerminate={this._onTouchEnd} // When 
        onResponderRelease can't call by some reason
      >
        {this.props.children}
 </View>
```

### Responder Event Handler Methods :

```
    if (this.isDoubleTap) {
      return false;
    }
    this.context.setScroll && this.context.setScroll(false);
    const currentTouchTimeStamp = Date.now();
    this._prevTouchInfo = {
      prevTouchX: nativeEvent.pageX,
      prevTouchY: nativeEvent.pageY,
      prevTouchTimeStamp: currentTouchTimeStamp
    };
    this.props.onStart(nativeEvent);
  };

  _onTouchMove = ({nativeEvent}) => {
    if (nativeEvent.touches.length <= 1) {
      if (this.isDoubleTap) {
        return false;
      }
      const self = this;
      const gesture = {
        x0: this._prevTouchInfo.prevTouchX,
        x1: nativeEvent.pageX,
        y0: this._prevTouchInfo.prevTouchY,
        y1: nativeEvent.pageY,
        dx: nativeEvent.pageX - this._prevTouchInfo.prevTouchX,
        dy: nativeEvent.pageY - this._prevTouchInfo.prevTouchY
      };
      InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(function () {
        self.props.onMove(nativeEvent, gesture);
      });
    }
  };

  _onTouchEnd = ({nativeEvent}) => {
      nativeEvent.touches.length === 0 && this.context.setScroll && this.context.setScroll(true);
    this.props.onEnd(nativeEvent);
  };
}
```

I am Developing an Application in React native.Actually when i am touch on Particular Position On view, getting the Corresponding x and y co-ordinates. App UI would look like this:

If this is still not enough functionality for android (eg. if you need multi-touch info), refer to [PanResponde](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder)

Comment: Maybe this article could help you! https://blog.reactnativecoach.com/creating-facebook-chat-head-bubbles-in-react-native-bdbbe338bb99

Comment: Thank You Mtg Kha Jeskai for suggestion but i need onMoveend Event method and above blog can't provide this type feature.